# tabs.onUpdated(tab) - link clicked or URL entered?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome history extension. I added a listener to `tabs.onUpdated()` to catch changes in the URL's of the various tabs. However I would like to discriminate an `onUpdated()` event caused by a click on a link in an opened page from an event caused by the user manually entering a new URL in an existing tab (or opening a bookmark). Both of them create `onUpdated()` events, which do not allow to discriminate between these two situations by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: Chrome generates a new tabId if a new URL is manually entered into the address bar. If the user follows a link, the tabId stays the same. Therefore watching the tabId will tell you how the address change came about

Comment: As of Chrome 79 (probably, earlier versions too, but I did not find when the change was made), Chrome no longer generates a new tabId in this scenario. Instead, webNavigation events can be used as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143480/4651679