# How to know if a new tab is opened by user click on new tab button?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

In Firefox WebExtensions, how to know in which way is the new tab opened?

- By user click on the new tab button (+)?
- By User click on a link such as `<a href="http://www.google.com/">`?

  > Note: I don't care if a new tab is opened by `window.open()`

I found that, in callback of `chrome.tabs.Tab.onCreated`, there is a parameter passed in, assume it is named as `firefoxTab`:

- For tabs opened by click on +, its URL is `about:newtab`
- For tabs opened by click on `<a href="" target="_blank">`, its URL is `about:blank`

**But**, there is an exception, if the second tab after Firefox started, is opened by click on "+", its URL will be `about:blank`, not `about:newtab`. I think it is a Firefox defect, have posted a bug on Bugzilla.

In the meantime, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please be more specific: `<a />` does not open a tab when clicked. Did you mean something like `<a href="" target="_blank">`?

Comment: @Makyen Yes, thanks for clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that this happens in Firefox 52.0 (testing on Nightly, Firefox 55.0a1 produced similar results).

The events that happen for clicking on the `+` for the first time upon restart are:

```
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 1 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 1, index: 1, windowId: 1, selected: false, highlighted: false, active: false, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: { muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:blank", title: "New Tab"}
tabs.onActivated                 ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 1, windowId: 1 }          
tabs.onHighlighted               ->  arg[0]= Object { tabIds: Array[1], windowId: 1 }          
tabs.onCreated                   ->  arg[0]= Object { id: 1, index: 1, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: { muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:blank", title: "New Tab"}
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 1 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "loading", url: "about:newtab" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 1, index: 1, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: { muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:newtab", title: "New Tab"}
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate   ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:newtab", timeStamp: 1489473167445, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 1 }          
webNavigation.onCommitted        ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:newtab", timeStamp: 1489473167466, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 1, transitionType: "link", transitionQualifiers: Array[0] }          
webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:newtab", timeStamp: 1489473167718, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 1 }          
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 1 :: arg[1]= Object { status: "complete" } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 1, index: 1, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: { muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:newtab", title: "New Tab"}
webNavigation.onCompleted        ->  arg[0]= Object { url: "about:newtab", timeStamp: 1489473167914, frameId: 0, parentFrameId: -1, tabId: 1 }          
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 1 :: arg[1]= Object { status: undefined } :: arg[2]= Object { id: 1, index: 1, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: { muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:newtab", title: "New Tab"}
```

The events upon clicking a second time on `+` are (yes, significantly fewer events, and no `webNavigation` events):

```
tabs.onActivated   ->  arg[0]= Object { tabId: 2, windowId: 1 }          
tabs.onHighlighted ->  arg[0]= Object { tabIds: Array[1], windowId: 1 }          
tabs.onCreated     ->  arg[0]= Object { id: 2, index: 2, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "complete", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: {"muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:newtab", title: "New Tab"}
```

Subsequent clicks on `+` resulted in similar events. Sometimes additional events are fired. In addition, some more events fire, depending on the contents of the `about:newtab` page.

In contrast, there are numerous additional events which occur when `<a href="" target="_blank">` is clicked.  Just the `tabs.onCreated` event is:

```
tabs.onCreated ->  arg[0]= Object { id: 3, index: 2, windowId: 1, selected: true, highlighted: true, active: true, pinned: false, status: "loading", incognito: false, width: 1098, height: 812, audible: false, mutedInfo: {"muted: false}, cookieStoreId: "firefox-default", url: "about:blank", title: "Connecting…"}
```

If you are wanting to differentiate, it appears that it is possible to look at the `title` and `url` provided in the `tabs.onCreated` event.  For a link, you have:

```
url: "about:blank", title: "Connecting…"
```

For clicking on the `+` you have either of the two following:

```
url: "about:blank", title: "New Tab"   //First `+`
url: "about:newtab", title: "New Tab"  //Subsequent `+`
```

Comment: Very helpful, I missed to check the `title` property.

Comment: New problem, if user install Firefox in native languages, `title` may be different than "New Tab", any suggestions on this?

Comment: When it exists (i.e. the first time `+` is clicked), the `webNavigation.onCommitted` event has the correct information for the URL. However, as indicated in the lists of events in the answer, that event does not fire for subsequent presses of `+`.

Comment: I think the `webNavigation.onCommitted` is triggered because the tab navigates from "about:blank" to "about:newtab". So it can't be used to determine how the new tab is opened. Because user can do such navigation by type "about:newtab" in the address bar.

Comment: If the user types the URL, then the `webNavigation.onCommitted`'s `transitionType` and `transitionQualifiers` will be different. See: [How to trigger an event only when the user changes the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42143480). Anther alternative would be for you to, when your extension is first installed, open a non-active tab (i.e. it does not have to be shown to the user) to `about:newtab` (and then immediately close it). You could then get the `title` text from the events for that tab and store it in `chrome.storage` to use. Periodically, you would want to double check that the user

Comment: I come up with a solution, to remember `tabs.onUpdated` history, and in `tabs.onCreated`, if its url is not "about:newtab", then check after 100 ms (user is not able to perform action in 100 ms, so if tab navigates in 100 ms, it must be performed by Firefox), to see if it has navigated to "about:newtab". If so, it should be opened by New Tab button. If not, it should be opened by link click.