# Intercept HTTP request errors only for top level frames (i.e. the URL shown in the URL bar)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In WebExtensions, there are APIs for intercepting HTTP requests and errors. When I tested `webRequest.onErrorOccurred` using this code:

The `manifest.json`:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "testOnError",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["testOnError.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest"
  ]
}
```

Then, the `testOnError.js`:

```
var target = "<all_urls>"; 

/*
e.g., with no network:
"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/"
NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESOLVED in Firefox
net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED in Chrome
*/

function logError(responseDetails) {  
  var errorURL=responseDetails.url;
  console.log("response url: "+errorURL);

  var errorCode=responseDetails.error;
  console.log("response error: "+ errorCode);
}
browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
  logError,
  {urls: [target]}
);
```

The API returns errors for requests that are not initiated from the URL bar.

If I am concerned only about requests and errors for navigation URL, i.e., including clicking on a link which changes the contents of the URL bar, but excluding background requests for images and other requests that I did not click on and I do not see in the URL bar, how can I enforce this? And how can I link the error URL with the request that caused it (i.e. how can I know the tab where the error comes from its URL bar)?

Comment: Related: [How to trigger an event only when the user changes the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143480)

Comment: @Makyen I edited the question. I do not find the link helpful.

Comment: Please define "in the URL bar only". Are you meaning *only* requests which result from the user typing into the URL bar, or do you mean from all navigation (e.g. including clicking on a link) which changes the contents of the URL bar (or some other definition)?

Comment: I mean `all navigation (e.g. including clicking on a link) which changes the contents of the URL bar`. That is, any URL changes the URL in the URL bar (address bar) but I do not care about requests going in the backgrounds for example, URL requests for images (which I never clicked on nor see them in the URL bar).

Comment: OK. That is *much* easier (to an extent). Please [edit] your question to reflect that instead of "initiated from the URL bar", which is only a subset of such requests (and much more difficult to filter for).  What you are interested in is to only look at requests which are for `frameId: 0`, which is the top level frame. You should be able to filter for that by using something like `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(logError,{urls:[target], types: ['main_frame']});`

Comment: Note that the above will not catch *all* changes to the URL bar. It will only catch those which are associated with a complete load of the HTML document. It is possible for the webpage to change the contents of the URL bar without completely reloading the document. If you want to catch that *also*, that is a more complex problem, as there may not be a `webRequest` directly associated with that type of change.

Comment: @Makyen yes, I want to capture redirects as well as long as the URL goes into the address (URL) bar.

Comment: Redirects are not what I was talking about. This question is about errors. What I've answered will capture errors within redirects, but not redirects without errors. You need to clearly define what you want to do. You appear to not have a clear understanding of all the possible ways things change, or at least you are not communicating it. What I was talking about are pages that change the URL bar without actually loading a new page. Such pages, usually, use AJAX to obtain the information for the new content and then replace some, or all, of the page's HTML without actually loading a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding `types: ['main_frame']` to the filter you are using on your call to [`webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onErrorOccurred).  This would look something like:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(logError, {
    urls‌​: [target],
    types: ['main_frame']
});
```

Your `logError` function will get called with an Object that look like:

```js
webRequest.onErrorOccurred - > arg[0] = Object {
    error: "NS_ERROR_NET_ON_RESOLVED",
    frameId: 0,
    fromCache: false,
    method: "GET",
    originUrl: undefined,
    parentFrameId: -1,
    requestId: "117",
    tabId: 2,
    timeStamp: 1497304152760,
    type: "main_frame",
    url: "http://www.exampleahdsafhd.com/"
}
```

You can know the tab that received this error by looking at the `tabId` property, which wil uniquely identify the tab.

Note that not all changes to the URL actually cause navigation to a new page. There are webpages which will change the address in the URL bar and independently use AJAX to fetch new content. This will not detect that type of update to the URL bar address, nor any requests associated with using AJAX to fetch such data.