# Chrome.tabs API - Check if a link was explicitly opened in a new tab/window by the user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am writing a chrome extension, where I am stuck having to detect if a tab was opened by default on a link (ex: using `_blank` or `window.open`), or was opened by the user explicitly using `ctrl+click` or `open in a new tab/window` context action.

Can I find if a tab was forced by the user, by using the chrome.tabs api?

Currently I am checking `tab.openerTabId` and I can filter out tabs originating from an existing tab, but how to check if the tab was explicitly opened?

Comment: chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted and transitionType property.

Comment: related: [How to trigger an event only when the user changes the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143480)

Comment: I don't believe this information is fully available in the background script from any of the APIs. You will probably need to use a content script to look at `target`, listen to click events (various ways), etc.

Comment: The onCommitted's transitionType can differentiate if the Url was typed or was received from another tab, but not if a link was forced onto a new tab. Perhaps there isn't a direct way.